# Calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} |x \sin x|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} |x \sin x|=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} |x| |\sin x|=+\infty$ because $|\sin x|$ is bounded but the result is that the limit doesn't exist.

Why?

Comment: Consider the sequence $\{-n\pi\}$ and $\{-n\pi/2\}$ converging to $-\infty$.

Comment: Try plotting and you'll see.

Comment: The zero function $z(x) = 0$ is also bounded, but this doesn't imply that $\lim_{x \to -\infty}|x z(x)| = +\infty$.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ecmbfju2r  ....Notice how graph jumps wildly from $0$ to $\infty$ and back again as it approaches $\infty$

Comment: Same reasoning: "$\lim_{x\to-\infty} 0 = \lim_{x \to -\infty} |x| \cdot 0 = +\infty$ because $0$ is bounded". So, obviously, something is very wrong.

Comment: $|\sin x|$ is bounded, but $|x|$ is not !

Answer (score 3):

Employ Heine's definition to prove that the limit does not exist:

> For functions on the real line, one way to define the limit of a function is in terms of the limit of sequences. In this setting:
> $$\lim _{x\to x_0}f(x)=A$$
> if and only if for **ALL** sequences $x_{n}$ (with $x_{n} \not = x_0$, $\forall n$) converging to $x_0$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $A$.

So, To provide that the limit does not exist, there must be two different sequences $(x_n')$ and $(x_n'')$ such that $f(x_n')$ and $f(x_n'')$ converge to different values.

Namely, it's easy to check that the following choices work: $$x_n'=-{\pi n} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ x_n''=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi n$$
Because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n')=0$$
while $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n'')=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

take the  sequence $x_n= - 2n\pi$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: for this particular sequence the limit of $|x_n \sin(x_n) |$, as $n$ tends to infinity is zero (trivially). But for the sequence $y_n= -(2n+1)\pi$ the limit of $|y_n \sin(y_n)|$, as $n$ tends to infinity, is infinity. (both these sequences tend to $-\infty$ as $n$ tends to infinity.)

Comment: @alphaomega, I think you meant $y_n=-(2n+1)\pi/2$, not just $(2n+1)\pi$.

Comment: @Barry Cipra yes of course! my bad. thank you