# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0}$ of piecewise $f(x)=1$ if $x=1/n$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ or $0$ otherwise on $[-1,1]$ doesn't exist.

Tags: limits, continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } x=\frac{1}{n}, \; n\in\mathbb{Z}\\0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

I want to prove with the Epsilon-Delta definition  that the limit as $x \to 0$  doesn't exist so I can say there is an essential discontinuity at $x=0$.

My reasoning is:

$\lim_{x\to 0}  f(x) \not= L$

Given any $\epsilon > 0$ , we can take  $\delta >0$ for which:

There exists $0 < |x| < \delta$ $\to$  $|f(x)-L|$ $≥$ $\epsilon$

So I'm trying to say that there are values of $x$ within $(-\delta, \delta)$ for which  $|f(x)-L|$ $≥$ $\epsilon$. I think what I wrote might be saying that, for any $\delta$ i choose, all values within $(-\delta, \delta)$ will result in  $|f(x)-L|$ $≥$ $\epsilon$, which I think isn't true no matter how infinitely small our chosen $\delta$ is.

How do I properly prove this?

Comment: YOu shall prove that There exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$ and $x_\delta\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x_\delta-0|<\delta$ but $|f(x_\delta)-f(0)|>\varepsilon$

Comment: Hello, you can also use the sequential characterization of limits. If $f$ had a limit $l$ at $0$, then for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converging to zero, $f(x_n)$ should converge to $l$ (you can try to prove this fact, which is very useful). However, you can find two sequences $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ for which $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ do converge, but not to the same limit. By the way, you could even find one single sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not have a limit as $n$ goes to infinity: Take $x_n=2/n$, for example and compute $f(x_n)$ for odd and even $n$.

Comment: Why should I take $|f(x_\delta)-L| = |f(x_\delta)-f(0)|$? To prove the limit isn't $0$?

Comment: Also, see this answer for the sake of another method (by Heine's definition): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3733225/752069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that the limit doesn't exist, you shouldn't start with *Given any $\epsilon \gt 0$...* but by finding **an** epsilon for which the definition of the limit won't be satisfied.

So suppose that the limit exists and its value is $L$. Now take $\epsilon = 1/3$. We have to prove that whatever $\delta \gt 0$ we pick, it exists $0 \lt \vert x \vert \lt \delta$ such that $\vert f(x) - L \vert \ge \epsilon = 1/3$.

Now it is quite simple and you can separate two cases.

**Case 1: $L \lt 1/2$**

Then you can find $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 \lt 1/n \lt \delta$ and you have
$$\vert f(1/n) -L \vert = \vert 1 -L \vert \gt 1/2 \gt 1/3.$$

**Case 2: $L \ge 1/2$**

In that case pick $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 \lt \sqrt 2/n \lt \delta$. Now
$$\vert f(\sqrt2/n) -L \vert = \vert 0 -L \vert \ge 1/2 \gt 1/3.$$

*Note: I picked up $\epsilon = 1/3$ because in all neighborhood of $0$ $f$ takes values at distance equal to $1$. And so, whatever $L$ would be, some function values would be at more than $1/3$ distance from the potential limit.*

Comment: Thank you. I assume this would be true for any $\epsilon < 1$ ? So I can say for any $\epsilon < 1$, there is no delta which satisfies the definition of a limit.

Comment: @312123 Yes, this is true. Any $\epsilon \lt 1$ would work.