# let $f: R\to R$ be $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x = 0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is $\space\lim\limits_{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = 0\space$?

Tags: calculus, limits

let $f: R\to R$ be  $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x = 0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ defined on a deleted neighbourhood of $x_0 \in R$.

and I'm trying to prove that $\space\lim\limits_{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = 0\space$ for every $\space a\in R$

I have managed to prove that for $a = 0, \lim\limits_{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = 0 $ but I'm having troubles trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = 0 $ when $a\ne 0$

That is my prove so far:

for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $ \delta$ such that for $0 < |x-a| < \delta $

$|f\left(x\right) - 0| < \epsilon$

and for $f(x) = 0$ it's obvious , but what about $f(x) = 1$ how do I choose a $\delta$ then? And isn't that mean that for $ 0<\epsilon<1\space $ $0$ is not the limit?

I'm new to calculus so I'm very sorry if my question is too easy and I'm just missing some definitions :(
but I would love to get an explanation so I can learn for next time.

Comment: You can close delta to be $\delta=\frac{|a-0|}{2}$, can you see how is that helpful?

Comment: Hint: what happens when $\delta=\frac{|a|}{2}$?

Comment: yes! then $x \ne 0 $! and $f(x) \ne 1$ thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3733225/752069) for Heine's definition of a limit of a function.

According to that, take
$$\forall (x_n): \lim x_n = 0, ~ x_n \ne 0$$
But, obviously (since $x_n \ne 0$), we have
$$\lim f(x_n) =\lim 0=0$$

Hence, the limit at $0$ is $0$.